# How to pass value to onclick function in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Guys how to pass two values to onclick function in Laravel, Please help.

```
   <a id="reply" onclick='loginmodal({{ '#collapseBox' . $comment->id . "," . Auth::user() ? true : false}}') role="button">Reply</a>
```

Comment: It's easy to change user  logged in status from javascript

Comment: Check Auth session at server side instead

Comment: I did that because I want to reply button to perform different task based on the login status. If user have login a reply section will show up otherwise login modal will pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay triple attention to proper quoting. What you probably want is:

```html
<a id="reply" onclick='loginmodal("{{ '#collapseBox' . $comment->id . "\"," . Auth::user() ? true : false }})' role="button">Reply</a>
```

Notice I added a `\"` before the `,` and reversed the order `')` to `)'`.

**Breakdown:**

Considering the template expression is:

```
{{ '#collapseBox' . $comment->id . "," . Auth::user() ? true : false }}
```

And it would evaluate to something like:

```
#collapseBox123,true
```

You would use its result like:

```html
<a id="reply" onclick='loginmodal("EXPRESSION_HERE)' role="button">Reply</a>
```

Where the end result would be:

```
<a id="reply" onclick='loginmodal("#collapseBox123,true)' role="button">Reply</a>
```

Which is wrong. Notice how `"#collapseBox123` does not close a string.

This is why I changed it to:

```
{{ '#collapseBox' . $comment->id . "\"," . Auth::user() ? true : false }}
```

Which gets you:

```
<a id="reply" onclick='loginmodal("#collapseBox123",true)' role="button">Reply</a>
```

---

There are other ways you can achieve the same result, like:

```
<a id="reply" onclick='loginmodal("#collapseBox{{ $comment->id }}", {{ Auth::user() ? true : false }})' role="button">Reply</a>
```

But, as I said, pay very much attention to the quoting.

Comment: I just tried your solution. The expression like this {{ '#collapseBox' . $comment->id . "\"," . Auth::user() ? true : false }} would only return 1 as parameter in the onclick function.    <a id="reply" onclick="loginmodal(1)" role="button">Reply</a> .   And I guess  1 is my user_id.

Comment: Try: `<a id="reply" onclick='loginmodal("#collapseBox{{ $comment->id }}", {{ Auth::user() ? true : false }})' role="button">Reply</a>`

Comment: Thanks for your help. This one work <a id="reply" onclick='loginmodal("#collapseBox{{ $comment->id }}", {{ Auth::user() ? true : false }})' role="button">Reply</a>

Comment: Yes it work. Even PhpStorm except this expression has grammar error on the comma.

Comment: PhpStorm is complaining, you say?

Comment: PhpStorm highlight the comma in the expression. I guess phpstorm seem it has grammar faults around comma area. But it running well on browser.

Comment: Maybe you could try reversing the quotes: `<a id="reply" onclick="loginmodal('#collapseBox{{ $comment->id }}', {{ Auth::user() ? true : false }})" role="button">Reply</a>` doesn't make sense, but it's worth the try, I guess.

Comment: I will try to play around with it later. Thanks for help me out.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
<a id="reply" onclick='loginmodal('#collapseBox{{$comment->id}}', '{{Auth::user() ? true : false}}') role="button">Reply</a>
```

Comment: Your suggestion similar to acdcjunior's. And it only return a numeric 1 as parameter in onclick function.